# Accessing nested dictionary data inside dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, python-requests

I am trying to access player data from a scrape of the OHL stats page. the code below gives me everything I need,

```
url = 'https://ontariohockeyleague.com/stats/players/68'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

statviewtype_url = "http://lscluster.hockeytech.com/feed/?feed=modulekit&view=statviewtype&type=topscorers&key=%s&fmt=json&client_code=ohl&lang=en&league_code=&season_id=68&first=0&limit=100&sort=active&stat=all&order_direction="

key = soup.find('div', id='stats')['data-feed_key']

r = requests.get(statviewtype_url % key)
statviewtype_data = json.loads(r.text)
d = json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

output:

```
Copyright     {'required_copyright': 'Official statistics pr...
Parameters    {'feed': 'modulekit', 'view': 'statviewtype', ...
Statviewtype  [{'player_id': '7889', 'shortname': 'M. Rossi'...
```

What I want is the Statviewtype dictionary (? I assume thats what it is). But when i try to access it with something like `print(df['Statviewtype'])` i get errors. Am i mixing up datatypes? Am I over-simplifying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe has 3 indexes `['Copyright', 'Parameters', 'Statviewtype']` and one column `['SiteKit']`. In order to read Statviewtype  you need:

```
df.loc['Statviewtype', 'SiteKit'][0]
```

Which specifies index Statviewtype and column SiteKit. Also note the `[0]` at the end. That is because the dictionary is inside a list in which the dictionary is the only element. But once that's done, you're good to go:

```
In []: df.loc['Statviewtype', 'SiteKit'][0].keys()
Out[]: dict_keys(['player_id', 'shortname', 'first_name', ... , 'namelink', 'teamlink', 'photo'])
```